# How to eliminate space between radio buttons in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I created a mobile landing page for a poll that I'd like to use. I used JQuery Mobile Themeroller to create this. Unfortunately, there's too much space between the radio buttons, which are aligned vertically.

I'm not an expert at CSS and I've experimented with different code but to no avail.

I included an pic attachment of what my landing page currently looks like and also an attachment of the landing page that it should look like.

I need the radio buttons to be closer together. They're spaced too far apart (vertically) and it looks a bit odd.

The landing page can be viewed at: http://daysofdogs.com

I've also attached it as an image to this post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: in your code while you create a radio button that time multiple space (&nbsp;) are added. if you remove this space then youe radio button design looks fine.

Comment: Thank you Hardik Trada. I will try this and report back.

Comment: I looked for the &nbsp; in the css code and it's nowhere to be found. it's also not in my html document. so that can't be it. could it be a padding issue?